# converting string to decimal c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

im doing some mvc.net nhibernate with datatable jquery and in my page i can search for any string as follow but i cant search by date or decimal ,any idea how to ?im totally new to programming. below is what i have tried and its successfully can search

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))

                        {
                            criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["SearchValue"] + "%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these for numbers:

```
criteria.Add(Expression.Between("YourNumber", minValue, maxValue))
criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("YourNumber", value))
```

Try these for dates:

```
criteria.Add(Expression.Le("YourDate", maxDate))
criteria.Add(Expression.Ge("YourDate", minDate) & Expression.Le("YourDate", maxDate))
```

'Eq' means 'Equal to', 'Le' means 'Less or equal to', 'Ge' means 'Greater or equal to'.

See the NHibernate documentation for [more examples](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html).
There are also related questions here on SO.